# c++ extracting double from stream

Tags: c++, iostream

I've a funny problem with school exercise. I am given latitude and longitude and I have to ensure that it is in right format: `\(\d+\.\d+[NS], \d\+.\d+[EW]\)`. So as you can see I have to check the `.`
is there.

```
char    lBracket, rBracket, comma, NS, EW;
int     nLat, nLon;
double  lat, lon;

istringstream iss ("(51.5N, 0.0E)");

iss >> fixed >> lBracket >> nLat >> lat >> NS >> comma >> 
                   nLon >> lon >> EW >> rBracket;
lat += nLat;
lon += nLon;
```

the `>> lon` extracts `".0E"` part (which is a valid double) but i need it to be extracted to EW.

Only solution I came up with is replace the `E` with some other letter, which would probably work, but isn't really nice piece of code.

Is there some other more elegant solution to this problem?

PS: You guessed right, no regular expressions allowed :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is not what you think. `.0E` is not a valid floating point numeral 
even in scientific notation. It lacks any exponent.

What is happening is that the stream parser is commited to the interpretation 
of `.0E` as a scientfic floating point numeral by the time it reaches the `E`, then 
finds no exponent; concludes that its interpretation is falsified; assigns 0 to 
the target double and set the `failbit` in `iss`, so no further extraction from the 
stream is possible. You could verify this by changing `0.0E` to `1.1E` and 
testing `iss.fail()` right after the attempted extraction of `lon.` You would 
still find that `lon` is set to 0, not 0.1, and that `iss.fail() == true`.

I believe there is no way to avoid this in the context `w.fE` (`w` = whole part, `f` = fractional part)
if you attempt to extract either the `w.f` or just the `.f` into a floating point variable with `>>`.
You are out of the comfort zone of formatted `>>` extraction in this corner case
and will need to get fiddly. And in fact that need does not spring solely from
the `w.fE` corner case, given the pattern `\(\d+\.\d+[NS], \d\+.\d+[EW]\)` that
you tell us the references must satisfy. The `\d+\.\d+[NS]` part is also too
exacting for `>> double >> char` or for `>> [unsigned|int] >> double >> char`:
the integral or floating point extractors would consume a leading `+` or `-`
and the floating point extractors would not insist on the presence of a
decimal point or on non-zero counts of digits both before and after it.

The fiddliness of parsing your map references (without aid of regexes) would 
prompt me to make a `map_ref` class for them, such that you can try to extract a
`map_ref` from an input stream (probably also from a string); can ask a `map_ref` 
whether it is a good or bad one (e.g. after an attempted extraction), and can insert
a formatted `map_ref` into an output stream.

Here is a sketch for such a class:

```
#include <ostream>
#include <istream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <utility>
#include <limits>

struct map_ref
{
    map_ref() = default;
    map_ref(char NS, double lat, char EW, double lon)
    :   _NS(NS == 'N' || NS == 'S' ? NS : '?'),
        _EW(EW == 'E' || EW == 'W' ? EW : '?'),
        _lat(lat >= 0.0 && lat <= 90.0 ? lat : -1),
        _lon(lon >= 0.0 && lon <= 180.0 ? lon : -1),
        _good(_NS != '?' && _EW != '?' && _lat != -1 && _lon != -1){}

    // Todo: string ctor

    std::pair<char,double> latitude() const {
        return std::make_pair(_NS,_lat);
    }

    std::pair<char,double> longitude() const {
        return std::make_pair(_EW,_lon);
    }

    // Todo: setters, getters, equality etc.

    bool good() const {
        return _good;
    }

    bool read(std::istream & in);

    std::ostream & write(std::ostream & out, std::size_t precision = 4) const {
        return out << std::fixed << std::setprecision(precision) << 
            '(' << _lat << _NS << ", " << _lon << _EW << ')';
    }

    void clear() {
        *this = map_ref();
    }

private:
    double 
    read_fixed_point(std::istream & in, char & dest, std::string const & delims);
    char _NS = '?';
    char _EW = '?';
    double _lat = -1;
    double _lon = -1;
    bool _good = false;
};

double 
map_ref::read_fixed_point(
    std::istream & in, char & dest, std::string const & delims)
{
    std::string s;
    unsigned whole_digs = 0, frac_digs = 0;
    while(in >> dest && 
            dest != '.' && delims.find(dest) == std::string::npos)
    {
        whole_digs += std::isdigit(dest) != 0;
        s += dest;
    }
    if (dest != '.') {
        return -1;
    }
    s += dest;
    while(in >> dest && delims.find(dest) == std::string::npos)
    {
        frac_digs += std::isdigit(dest) != 0;
        s += dest;
    }
    if (whole_digs == 0 || frac_digs == 0 ||
        whole_digs + frac_digs > std::numeric_limits<double>::digits10 ||
        s.length() != 1 + whole_digs + frac_digs) {
            return -1;
    }
    return std::stod(s);
}


bool map_ref::read(std::istream & in)
{
    char lparen = 0;
    clear();
    in >> std::noskipws >> lparen;
    if (lparen != '(') {
        return _good = false;
    }
    _lat = read_fixed_point(in,_NS,"NS");
    if (_lat < 0.0 || _lat > 90.0) {
        return _good = false;
    }
    char comma = 0;
    in >> comma;
    if (comma != ',') {
        return _good = false;
    }
    while (std::isspace(in.peek())) {
        _EW = in.get();
    }
    _lon = read_fixed_point(in,_EW,"EW");
    if (_lon < 0.0 || _lon > 180.0) {
        return _good = false;
    }
    char rparen = 0;
    in >> rparen;
    return _good = rparen == ')';
}

std::istream & operator>>(std::istream & in, map_ref & mr)
{
    mr.read(in);
    return in;
}

std::ostream & operator<<(std::ostream & out, map_ref const & mr)
{
    return mr.write(out);
}
```

The class incorporates the obvious constraints that the latitude in a good 
`map_ref` shall be <= 90 North or South, and that the longitude shall be <= 180 East or West.

The `read(std::istream &)` method parses map references as per your pattern, 
with the slight relaxation that 0 or more spaces are acceptable after the comma.
Note that it classifies a parsed map reference as *bad* if either the
latitude or longitude contains more digits than can be respresented without change
in a `double` (i.e. more than [`std::numeric_limits<double>::digits10`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/numeric_limits/digits10)
== 15)

The method:

```
std::ostream & write(std::ostream & out, std::size_t precision = 4)
```

lets you specify the precision with which the latitude and longitude will
be represented in the output stream, as per [`std::set_precision(precision)`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/setprecision) or
accept the default `4`. If you set it to 0, then you'll lose all decimal places
on output, so don't do that.

The class comes with overloads of the global operators `>>` and `<<` for
formatted extraction and insertion of `map_ref`s. They delegate
respectively to `map_ref::read` and `map_ref::write`, with the default precision
in the latter case; so for any other output precision, invoke `map_ref::write`
directly.

For some tests of `map_ref` parsing, you can append the following:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>

static unsigned tests = 0, pass = 0, fail = 0;

static void expect_good(char NS, double lat, char EW, double lon )
{
    std::cout << "Testing (" << ++tests << ") " 
        << NS << ',' << lat << ',' << EW << ',' << lon << '\n';
    map_ref mr(NS,lat,EW,lon);
    if (!mr.good()) {
        std::cerr << "Failed (" << tests << "): Is good, got bad\n";
        ++fail;
    } else {
        ++pass;
        std::cout << "Passed (" << tests << "): Is good. Got \"" << mr << "\"\n";  
    }
}

static void expect_bad(char NS, double lat, char EW, double lon )
{
    std::cout << "Testing (" << ++tests << ") " 
        << NS << ',' << lat << ',' << EW << ',' << lon << '\n';
    map_ref mr(NS,lat,EW,lon);
    if (mr.good()) {
        std::cerr << "Failed (" << tests << "): Is bad, got good\n";
        ++fail;
    } else {
        ++pass;
        std::cout << "Passed (" << tests << "): Is bad, got bad\n";  
    }
}

static void expect_good(std::string const & s)
{
    std::cout << "Testing (" << ++tests << ") \"" << s << "\"\n";
    std::istringstream iss(s);
    map_ref mr;
    iss >> mr;
    if (!mr.good()) {
        std::cerr << "Failed (" << tests << "): Is good, got bad\n";
        ++fail;
    } else {
        ++pass;
        std::cout << "Passed (" << tests << "): Is good. Got \"" << mr << "\"\n";  
    }
}

static void expect_bad(std::string const & s)
{
    std::cout << "Testing (" << ++tests << ") \"" << s << "\"\n";
    std::istringstream iss(s);
    map_ref mr;
    iss >> mr;
    if (mr.good()) {
        ++fail;
        std::cerr << "Failed (" << tests << "): Is bad, got good\n";
    } else {
        ++pass;
        std::cout << "Passed (" << tests << "): Is bad, got bad\n"; 
    }
}


int main()
{
    expect_bad('E',1.00,'S',1.00);
    expect_bad('N',-1.00,'W',1.00);
    expect_bad('N',90.00,'W',180.01);
    expect_bad('S',90.01,'W',180.00);
    expect_good('S',90.00,'E',180.00);
    expect_good('S',0.0,'E',0.0);
    expect_bad("");
    expect_bad("1.1N, 2.2W");
    expect_bad("(1.1N, 2.2W");
    expect_bad("1.1N, 2.2W)");
    expect_bad("[1.1N, 2.2W)");
    expect_bad("(1.1N, 2.2W(");
    expect_bad("(N)");
    expect_bad("(N, W)");
    expect_bad("(0N, 1W)");
    expect_bad("(1.0N, 2W)");
    expect_bad("(1.0N, .2W)");
    expect_bad("(.01N, 1.2E)");
    expect_bad("(1.N, 1.2W)");
    expect_bad("(N1.1, E1.2)");
    expect_bad("(1.0N, 1.2 W)");
    expect_bad("(1.0X, 1.2W)");
    expect_bad("(1.0N, 1.2Z)");
    expect_bad("(+1.0N, 1.2E)");
    expect_bad("(1.+0N, 1.2E)");
    expect_bad("(1.0N, -1.2E)");
    expect_bad("(1.0N, 1.-2E)");
    expect_bad("(1.1N, 2.3.4E)");
    expect_bad("(0.0NN, 0.0E)");
    expect_bad("(0.0N, 0.0EW)");
    expect_bad("(0.0 1N, 0.0E)");
    expect_bad("(0.01N, 0 2.0E)");
    expect_bad("(0 .01N, 2.0E)");
    expect_bad("(0.01N, 2. 0E)");
    expect_bad("(12.34567890123456N, 2.0E)");
    expect_good("(0.0N, 0.0E)");
    expect_good("(1.0N,1.2W)");
    expect_good("(01.0N,01.2W)");
    expect_good("(1.0N,  1.2W)");
    expect_good("(0.123456789N, 0.000000001E)");
    expect_good("(0.000000001S, 0.123456789W)");
    expect_good("(0.123456789N, 0.000000001W)");
    expect_good("(0.000000001S, 0.123456789E)");
    expect_good("(1.1N, 12.3456789012345E)");
    expect_bad("(0.1E, 0.1N)");
    expect_bad("(0.1W, 0.1S)");
    expect_bad("(0.1W, 0.1N)");
    expect_bad("(0.1E, 0.1S)");
    expect_good("(90.0N, 180.0E)");
    expect_good("(90.0S, 180.0W)");
    expect_good("(90.0N, 180.0W)");
    expect_good("(90.0S, 180.0E)");
    expect_bad("(90.000001N, 180.0E)");
    expect_bad("(90.000001S, 180.0W)");
    expect_bad("(90.0N, 180.000001W)");
    expect_bad("(90.0S, 180.000001E)");
    std::cout << "Tests: " << tests << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Passed: " << pass << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Failed: " << fail << std::endl;  
    return 0;
}
```

(gcc 4.9.2/clang 3.6, -std=c++11)

Comment: How do you handle 7-digit fractions, and distinguish between 50.0000123 and 50.123? This code needs serious work to manage such details.  Incidentally, the code returns 62.3 when the user does type 50.123.

Comment: See also [Ignore E when reading double with sscanf](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29563849/ignore-e-when-reading-double-with-sscanf)

Comment: @JonathanLeffler I stand corrected. The answer was egregiously broken. I hope the update isn't.

Answer (score 0):

You're essentially looking at a parse problem. `operator>>(istream&, string&)` is a very simplistic parser that just tokenizes on whitespace.

If your format specification is strict enough, and you should reject `(51.5N , 0.0E)` (extra space before comma) then just don't extract the comma. Instead, directly after extraction you should check that `nLat` contains the trailing comma and remove it. You no longer need `>>comma`.

If you must support optional whitespace anywhere, it may help to preprocess the string by inserting an extra space before and after the comma (unconditionally). If there already was a space, there will now be two. That's no problem as whitespace skipping will skip any amount.

Comment: Typical math approach, this: if you already have a solution for X, it's sufficient to turn your actual problem Y into X.

Answer (score 0):

You can replace `E` with `X` (for example) in the input string, after running your code you can replace back `X` with `E` in `EW` variable.

```
char    lBracket, rBracket, comma, NS, EW;
int     nLat, nLon;
double  lat, lon;

std::string inputString = "(51.5N, 0.0E)";
size_t e_pos = inputString.find( 'E' );
if ( e_pos != std::string::npos ) {
    inputString.replace( e_pos, e_pos + 1, 'X' );
}
istringstream iss ( inputString );

iss >> fixed >> lBracket >> nLat >> lat >> NS >> comma >> 
                   nLon >> lon >> EW >> rBracket;

if ( EW == 'X' ) {
    EW = 'E';
}

lat += nLat;
lon += nLon;
```

**Update:** Sorry, didn't see your remark

> Only solution I came up with is replace the E with some other letter, which would probably work, but isn't really nice piece of code.

If you want - I'll delete an answer

Comment: Don't delete it. It is a valid answer, although not the one I was looking for, but it still could be useful to somebody :)