# Ignore 'E' when reading double with sscanf

Tags: c++, c, scanf

I have input such as `"(50.1003781N, 14.3925125E)"` .These are latitude and longitude.

I want to parse this with

```
sscanf(string,"(%lf%c, %lf%c)",&a,&b,&c,&d);
```

but when `%lf` sees `E` after the number, it consumes it and stores it as number in exponential form. Is there way to disable this?

Comment: one option would be to break your input string down into substrings and scan from there.

Comment: You could replace the `E` with a place holder value and then change `b` or `d` to `E` if it has the placeholder.

Comment: Can you move so that all your longitudes are W instead of E?

Comment: Not sure if I understand your question, i will be stroing these coordinates i read later, if its W i store is as negative double, if its E il lstore ti as positive number

Comment: If you're not sure about my question, rest easy.  It is mostly a joke.  You probably can't afford to pretend that longitudes east do not exist.

Comment: Maybe duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29381290/c-extracting-double-from-stream

Comment: @borisbn: related, but that is a problem in C++ using the C++ I/O operators.  This is primarily in C, though I see it does have the C++ tag.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler I'm agree with you, but one of solutions in that question is puraly `C` and OP can use it

Comment: suggest storing lat/lon values like a gps would output them.  I.E. separate each field with a comma  so this input: (50.1003781N, 14.3925125E) would actually be stored as: (50.1003781,N, 14.3925125,E)

Comment: In April, I commented here on [SO 29381290](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29381290/) noting that there were problems with the C++ code.  Since making that comment (which I've now deleted), the code has been comprehensively fixed.  But it remains C++ code.  My answer here is C code; it can readily be upgraded to C++ code.  (The primary problem is the `goto error;` statements skipping over `int c = toupper((unsigned char)*end++);` — and the secondary problems are the use of C-style casts such as `(unsigned char)*end++`.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you'll need to do manual parsing, probably using `strtod()`.  This shows that `strtod()` behaves sanely when it comes up against the trailing `E` (at least on Mac OS X 10.10.3 with GCC 4.9.1 — but likely everywhere).

```
#include <errno.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void)
{
    const char latlong[] = "(50.1003781N, 14.3925125E)";
    char *eptr;
    double d;
    errno = 0;      // Necessary in general, but probably not necessary at this point
    d = strtod(&latlong[14], &eptr);
    if (eptr != &latlong[14])
        printf("PASS: %10.7f (%s)\n", d, eptr);
    else
        printf("FAIL: %10.7f (%s) - %d: %s\n", d, eptr, errno, strerror(errno));

    return 0;
}
```

Compilation and run:

```
$ gcc -O3 -g -std=c11 -Wall -Wextra -Werror latlong.c -o latlong
$ ./latlong
PASS: 14.3925125 (E))
$
```

Basically, you'll skip white space, check for an `(`, `strtod()` a number, check for `N` or `S` or lower case versions, comma, `strtod()` a number, check for `W` or `E`, check for `)` maybe allowing white space before it.

Upgraded code, with moderately general `strtolatlon()` function based on `strtod()` et al.  The 'const cast' is necessary in the functions such as `strtod()` which take a `const char *` input and return a pointer into that string via a `char **eptr` variable.

```
#include <ctype.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#define CONST_CAST(type, value) ((type)(value))

extern int strtolatlon(const char *str, double *lat, double *lon, char **eptr);

int strtolatlon(const char *str, double *lat, double *lon, char **eptr)
{
    const char *s = str;
    char *end;
    while (isspace(*s))
        s++;
    if (*s != '(')
        goto error;
    *lat = strtod(++s, &end);
    if (s == end || *lat > 90.0 || *lat < 0.0)
        goto error;
    int c = toupper((unsigned char)*end++);
    if (c != 'N' && c != 'S')  // I18N
        goto error;
    if (c == 'S')
        *lat = -*lat;
    if (*end != ',')
        goto error;
    s = end + 1;
    *lon = strtod(s, &end);
    if (s == end || *lon > 180.0 || *lon < 0.0)
        goto error;
    c = toupper((unsigned char)*end++);
    if (c != 'W' && c != 'E')  // I18N
        goto error;
    if (c == 'E')
        *lon = -*lon;
    if (*end != ')')
        goto error;
    if (eptr != 0)
        *eptr = end + 1;
    return 0;

error:
    if (eptr != 0)
        *eptr = CONST_CAST(char *, str);
    errno = EINVAL;
    return -1;
}

int main(void)
{
    const char latlon1[] = "(50.1003781N, 14.3925125E)";
    const char latlon2[] = "   (50.1003781N, 14.3925125E) is the position!";
    char *eptr;
    double d;
    errno = 0;      // Necessary in general, but Probably not necessary at this point
    d = strtod(&latlon1[14], &eptr);
    if (eptr != &latlon1[14])
        printf("PASS: %10.7f (%s)\n", d, eptr);
    else
        printf("FAIL: %10.7f (%s) - %d: %s\n", d, eptr, errno, strerror(errno));

    printf("Converting <<%s>>\n", latlon2);
    double lat;
    double lon;
    int rc = strtolatlon(latlon2, &lat, &lon, &eptr);
    if (rc == 0)
        printf("Lat: %11.7f, Lon: %11.7f; trailing material: <<%s>>\n", lat, lon, eptr);
    else
        printf("Conversion failed\n");

    return 0;
}
```

Sample output:

```
PASS: 14.3925125 (E))
Converting <<   (50.1003781N, 14.3925125E) is the position!>>
Lat:  50.1003781, Lon: -14.3925125; trailing material: << is the position!>>
```

That is *not* comprehensive testing, but it is illustrative and close to production quality.  You might need to worry about infinities, for example, in true production code.  I don't often use `goto`, but this is a case where the use of `goto` simplified the error handling.  You could write the code without it; if I had more time, maybe I would upgrade it.  However, with seven places where errors are diagnosed and 4 lines required for reporting the error, the `goto` provides reasonable clarity without great repetition.

Note that the `strtolatlon()` function explicitly identifies errors via its return value; there is no need to guess whether it succeeded or not.  You can enhance the error reporting if you wish to identify where the error is.  But doing that depends on your error reporting infrastructure in a way this does not.

Also, the `strtolatlon()` function will accept some odd-ball formats such as `(+0.501003781E2N, 143925125E-7E)`.  If that's a problem, you'll need to write your own fussier variant of `strtod()` that only accepts fixed-point notation.  On the other hand, there's a [meme/guideline](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Robustness_principle) "Be generous in what you accept; be strict in what you produce".  That implies that what's here is more or less OK (it might be good to allow optional white space before the N, S, E, W letters, the comma and the close parenthesis).  The converse code, `latlontostr()` or `fmt_latlon()` (with `strtolatlon()` renamed to `scn_latlon()`, perhaps) or whatever, would be careful about what it produces, only generating upper-case letters, and always using the fixed format, etc.

```
int fmt_latlon(char *buffer, size_t buflen, double lat, double lon, int dp)
{
    assert(dp >= 0 && dp < 15);
    assert(lat >=  -90.0 && lat <=  90.0);
    assert(lon >= -180.0 && lon <= 180.0);
    assert(buffer != 0 && buflen != 0);
    char ns = 'N';
    if (lat < 0.0)
    {
        ns = 'S';
        lat = -lat;
    }
    char ew = 'W';
    if (lon < 0.0)
    {
        ew = 'E';
        lon = -lon;
    }
    int nbytes = snprintf(buffer, buflen, "(%.*f%c, %.*f%c)", dp, lat, ns, dp, lon, ew);
    if (nbytes < 0 || (size_t)nbytes >= buflen)
        return -1;
    return 0;
}
```

Note that 1 unit at 7 decimal places of a degree (10<sup>-7</sup> ˚) corresponds to about a centimetre on the ground (oriented along a meridian; the distance represented by a degree along a parallel of latitude varies with the latitude, of course).

Answer (score 4):

Process the string first using

```
char *p;
while((p = strchr(string, 'E')) != NULL) *p = 'W';
while((p = strchr(string, 'e')) != NULL) *p = 'W';

// scan it using your approach

sscanf(string,"(%lf%c, %lf%c)",&a,&b,&c,&d);

// get back the original characters (converted to uppercase).

if (b == 'W') b = 'E';    
if (d == 'W') d = 'E';
```

`strchr()` is declared in the C header `<string.h>`.

Note:  This is really a C approach, not a C++ approach.   But, by using `sscanf()` you are really using a C approach.

Comment: thanks, and what would be c++ approach? this is part of c++ project I just couldnt think of anythinkg else then trying to use sscanf for this

Comment: Using `'W'` is probably not the best idea. What if I'm going west ?

Comment: At the least, you need to record whether you changed `E` or `e` to `W` so that you can undo the change after using `sscanf()`.  You probably want to record the original character so you can put the string back to how it was.  Of course, this approach also means you can't scan string literals containing a latitude/longitude.

Comment: Yeah, okay.   The point is changing the character in order to scan, and recording enough information so the values can be retrieved (e.g. multiply by -1 if changing E-W).   A valid coordinate will not have distinct East and West coordinates.   A whole swag of error checking would be needed both before and after the point of trying to scan for coordinates (checking the string only contains a pair of coordinates, checking return from sscanf(), etc etc).

Comment: A C++ approach would make use of the std::string type (and probably not name a variable as "string").  There are various operations supported by std::string to replace substrings, etc.    For the scanning/parsing (instead of sscanf()), one way is to feed the string to a std::istringstream and use that to extract values.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to read all the string and then to replace E with another chracter