# Extraction operator reads in 0 incorrectly but reads correct number in similar cases

Tags: c++

So I'm reading in user input that has the form 1U = 1.2A the only variation is that A will be a different letter from B to E. I will be receiving 7 such inputs. One for each letter A through E. I need to extract the floating point number next to the A. So in the previous example I trying to get 1.2. I do this by putting the user input into an istringstream variable and extrafting what I need from there

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
using namespace std;

string rateInfo;
istringstream inSS;
double rate[7], temp;

for (int i = 0; i < 7; i++) {
    getline(cin, rateInfo);
    inSS.clear();
    inSS.str(rateInfo);
    inSS.ignore(5);
    inSS >> temp;
    rate[i] = temp;
}
```

This code actually mostly works. Except for when i = 4. The specific input I'm testing when i = 4 is 1U = 5.6E. Instead of reading in 5.6 it reads in 0.

I also discovered if input 1U = 5.6 instead of 1U = 5.6E my code works perfectly. I've also tested different numbers along with E such as 6.54 and 1.23 and still everything works except for the E case. So it seems something about the letter E is breaking my code.

I know that the extraction operator reading in 0 is one of the things that can happen when the stream is in an error state but for the life of me I can't figure out exactly what is wrong. Especially since it works for every letter except E.

Comment: It's nearly an [mcve], just needs to be put in `main()`, and you have to supply the inputs. And perhaps simplify a bit.

Comment: Related: [c++ extracting double from stream](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29381290/33499) and [Ignore 'E' when reading double with sscanf](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29563849/33499)

Comment: When reading a floating point value, the `E` (or `e`, since case doesn't matter) means there should be a integral value following which is an exponent.   For example, `5.6E1` means "5.6 times 10 to the power of one" i.e. `56`, not `5.6` and `5.6E-1` means `0.56`.    If the `E` is not followed by an exponent, reading the floating point value fails.   Since you are using `E` to mean something different, you need to adjust your reading accordingly (e.g. check for the presence of letters, then truncate the string, before reading the floating point value).

Comment: @wimh @ Peter Thank y'all I learned quite a bit.

Comment: Per wimh: possible duplicate of [c++ extracting double from stream](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29381290/c-extracting-double-from-stream)